# ordinal numbers modifying uncountable nouns?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, ordinals

I'd like to know whether it is grammatical in contemporary English to modify an uncountable noun with ordinal numbers.
Is it right to say, "**first** disobedience" or "**second** importance"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95855/discussion-on-question-by-apollyon-ordinal-numbers-modifying-uncountable-nouns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposed answer: A solid **maybe** - though the meaning is usually more specific than the use without an ordinal number. It is not very common and is *typically* a shortened way to refer to an already discretized version of the word (eg. dropping "pieces")

Examples:

[This site](https://ieltsliz.com/uncountable-nouns-word-list/) has a list of uncountable nouns. What follows are examples of what it lists as "uncountable words" being used with ordinal numbers, followed by an alternate phrasing that introduces a countable noun:

> **equipment**
>
> > At the first time increment the probability of failure of the [first equipment](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=UDAwZQO8ZGUC&pg=SA7-PA30&lpg=SA7-PA30&dq=%22first+equipment%22+example&source=bl&ots=2oZo5E_N_V&sig=ACfU3U2pNuaLcIWsEOwmaBBThlz_OirFQg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFvZj48KTjAhWSwJQKHdrEATkQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22first%20equipment%22%20example&f=false) is calculated.
> >
> > ... first *piece* of equipment ...
>
> **evidence**
>
> > This marks the [first evidence](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/05/01/world/denisovan-fossil-discovery-scn/index.html) of Denisovans found outside Denisova Cave in Siberia since the mysterious ancient human group was discovered in 2010.
> >
> > ... the first *piece* of evidence ...
>
> **news**
>
> > On today's edition of Forza Monthly, the studio's own Brian Ekberg confirmed that the [first news](https://www.windowscentral.com/first-news-new-forza-motorsport-game-coming-may-7) of the project will be coming on May 7 in the next edition of the show.
> >
> > ... the first *piece* of news ...
>
> **sunshine**
>
> > It was a beautiful winter's day, bright and crisp, the [first sunshine] London had seen in weeks.
> >
> > ... the first *day/moment* of sunshine ...
>
> **importance**
>
> > Of [second importance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4407870/) are the three anti-PM/Scl-positive DM patients.
> >
> > The second most important items ... [could not think of a better rephrasing for this]

---

As you can see there are cases where an ordinal number can be used with an uncountable noun. The most common usage (and easiest to find) are ones using **"the first [uncountable]"** format, that refer to something that is/was "the first in time". This usage is context- and word-specific as to whether it is "grammatical" or "idiomatic".

As with most English grammar rules, there are exceptions to the rule that ordinal numbers are not used with uncountable nouns.